# changing 0019 year to 2019

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have date with year thats 19 but is actually coming out as 0019 instead of 2009.  ORDER_DATE is a date field.

So when I do

```
select ORDER_DATE, TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD') from table abc
```

I get:

```
30-JUN-19   0019/06/30
30-APR-19   0019/04/30
31-DEC-21   2021/12/31
23-JAN-19   2019/01/23
```

Is there way to change 0019 year to 2019?

I tried:

```
SELECT case when extract(year from ORDER_DATE) = 19 
    then add_months (ORDER_DATE,24000) 
    else ORDER_DATE 
end as fixed_date 
from abc
```

But not sure if thats the best way.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it.

```
select ORDER_DATE, REPLACE(TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD'), '0019', '2019') from table abc
```

Comment: That will produce a string in `YYYY/MM/DD` format, not a date.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your 2019 dates are actually wrong. You should *really* investigate what caused this bad data to come into your database and fix that.

Your approach to change the dates on the fly in the query is fine for 2019. I would suggest taking a step further and actually fixing your data, so you don't need to worry about that later on (assuming that you found and fixed the cause for the bad values). Here is a generic approach that adds 2000 years to any date before year 100:

```
update mytable
set order_date = add_months(order_date, 12 * 2000)
where extract(year from mytable) < 100
```

You might want to adapt the boundary to your actual issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes, updating data would be the ideal, but if I want to fix it, whats the easiest solution?  was trying something like if year is 19 then 2019 and then add the month and date but when I tried that it was complaining about wrong data type,  I thought to char is text and that I can concatenate '2019' to TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'MM-DD')?

Answer (score 0):

To query with dates corrected:

```
select order_date
     , case when to_number(to_char(order_date,'CC')) = 1
           then order_date + numtoyminterval(2000, 'YEAR')
           else order_date
       end as fixed_date 
from   demo;
```

To fix the data:

```
update demo
set    order_date = order_date + numtoyminterval(2000, 'YEAR')
where  order_date < date '1000-01-01';
```

This handles years other than 0019, and also preserves any time component.